# sending data as list from HTML template to flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I found out that the `select` HTML tag has an attribute `multiple` which allows you to select multiple items and returns it as a list.

My form is set up like this

```
<form action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter title here" name="title">

        <input type="file" class="form-control my-4" name="file" required aria-required="true">

        <select name="categories" id="category" multiple class="form-control mt-4">
                <option value="comedy">comedy</option>
                <option value="Tech">Tech</option>
                <option value="Art">Art</option>
                <option value="classic">Classic</option>
                <option value="Nature">Nature</option>
        </select>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Publish</button>
```

I've tried collecting the form data from this tag in my flask app using `request.form.getlist()` but it keeps returning an empty list and I really need this data in form of a list. Please I need help

Comment: This should work, assuming you are using the `name` attr of the `select` tag. i.e.: `request.form.getlist("categories")`. If that's not the error, would it be possible to see the Flask Python route that handles the POST form?

Comment: what did you use as argument in `getlist()`? It has to be `name` from `select`, not `id`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show how you use `getlist()`
but often problem is that people use `id` instead of `name`.

---

Minimal working code:

I use `getlist("categories")` because I have `name="categories"`

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    print('args :', request.args)
    print('form :', request.form)
    print('json :', request.json)
    print('files:', request.files)
    print('data :', request.data)

    print('categories:', request.form.getlist("categories"))
    
    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="title"><br/>

    <input type="file" name="file"><br/>

    <select name="categories" multiple id="blablabla">
        <option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
        <option value="Tech">Tech</option>
        <option value="Art">Art</option>
        <option value="Classic">Classic</option>
        <option value="Nature">Nature</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">Publish</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```

---

**EDIT:**

I added also `id="blablabla"` (but I could add the same `id="categories"`) but all browsers always use `name` to send form information to server (since browsers were created in the 90's).

And all elements should have `name` - `<input>`, `<select>`, `<button>`, `<textarea>`, etc.
If element doesn't have `name` then browser doesn't send it to server (and `id` can't change it).
If element has `name` then browser sends it even if it is empty.
Exception can be `select` and `checkbox` which has to be selected/checked to send value(s).

And all frameworks and laguages have to use value from `name`, not from `id`.

Comment: I removed the id attribute and it started working fine. I'm not sure if it's a general rule, specific to flask or maybe some problem in my configuration, I'm just glad it works. Thank you for the help

Comment: all browsers always use `name` to send form information (since they were created in the 90's) - the same is for all `<input>` and `<button>`. So the same is in all frameworks and languages.

Comment: you can keep `id` in HTML but you have to also keep `name`, and in `Flask` use value from `name` - `categories` (not `category` from `id`)